# Adding Unused C-Wire for Nest Thermostat

Tags: hvac, furnace, thermostat-c-wire, nest

[image]

I'm having an issue with my NEST thermostat short cycling my air handler fan while in running AC.  This is a known issue, and the fix seems to be adding a common wire to the NEST.

My thermostat is wired with 18-5, and currently the yellow wire is unused.  I want to use this for the common.  Pic of the board is attached.  Humidifier and AC compressor are wired to board.

Can I just add the Yellow wire to the C terminal without changing anything else? I should probably pigtail the 3rd wire, correct?

Sorry for the dumb questions, I just want to make sure I've got it right.

Thanks

ETA: Picture of terminal block

Left to right: R C W Y G

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what are the letter codes below the screw terminals.

Comment: Sorry, didnt realize they weren't visable when I downsized the pic. They are, from left to right:  R, C, W, Y, G.  I'll put a pic below.

Answer (score 1):

It would be preferable to use the blue wire instead. The conventions for colors assign `Yellow` to cooling. The other colors also have standard assignments.

The `Blue` wire from a 18-5 bundle is what would be best for the `C` common.

If following recommendations to the letter, then the three wires connecting to `C` should be pigtailed.

Comment: Thanks.  Right now the blue wire is on the Y terminal on the board, and Y1 at the NEST.  I'll swap the yellow to Y on the board, Y1 on the nest, and Blue to Common.